# Relationship between "Task Parallel Library" and "Task-based Asynchronous Pattern"?

Tags: .net, multithreading

In the context of C#, .NET 4/4.5 used for an application running on a web-server, what is the relationship between "[Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" and "[Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)"?

I understand one is a library and the other is a pattern. But to dig deeper, is it like "The library is used by the pattern to enforce good practices". I'm also not clear if both are supported in .NET 4.0 (with `await` and `async` keywords)

Edit: Seems that `await` and `async` are only in .NET 4.5 ...

Comment: One is a library that helps with running tasks in parallel. The other is a programming pattern for asynchronous tasks. They can work together. As an aside - you really should be linking to the sources of both phrases in your question.

Comment: clarified and linked up

Comment: Read the articles you've linked. They explain it pretty well (the *first* sentence in the Task-based AP article clarifies your edit)

Comment: Concurrency and asynchrony though handled similarly because they both involve non-deterministic execution from the perspective of their initiators, they are not in fact the same. That said, I *think* the TAP is just another way of saying CPS so have a read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style

Comment: async and await are C# features, not .Net features, although in the case of the `Task` class, the methods required by the compiler only exist in .Net 4.5. You can use async/await in .Net 4 using the 'async targeting pack': http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - TAP is just a number of conventions around methods returning `Task` instances, and is not directly related to CPS. The C# async/await features simplify writing task continuations however.

Comment: @Lee Thanks for the tip! Yeah I'm aware the async/await are for continuations, but they're an attempt at true coroutines where you don't need CPS, I just glanced at the TAP thing and it sounded like it was a newer form of the begin/end CPS. My mistake!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will .NET 4.5 Make the Reactive Extensions Obsolete?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117905/will-net-4-5-make-the-reactive-extensions-obsolete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TPL is a new(ish) framework that provides a simplified API for concurrent programming. The Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern is a framework design guideline that leverages the TPL to deliver consistently designed concurrent operations.

The async/await keywords are syntactic sugar that allow you to consume TAP APIs without diving into the details of continuation.

Comment: so TPL extends TAP or TAP extends TPL? Put another way, TPL is newer/preferred compared to TAP?

Comment: @mmcrae - if I understand correctly, they are not extensions of each other.  It seems from this answer that TPL is a framework to make life easier for developers. TAP is a design guideline (a pattern) that uses TPL as part of its guideline/recommendation for how to design concurrent operations in a consistent way. Michael Brown - I have explained that accurately?